# Displaying a message when jQuery filter returns nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I found code online that filters elements by their text content.
How can I display a message when there is no match?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data('value').toUpperCase();
  $("div").filter(function(index) {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

```html
<button>example</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `filter()` to toggle each item based on state, like using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). But one advantage of `filter()` is that you can return a reduced selection and count the items it contains. That value can determine whether a "no match" message should be displayed.

> ... the .filter() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; all elements matching the selector will be included in the result. -- [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selection).
>
> For each element, if the function returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded. -- [Using a Filter Function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function)

So, instead of toggling items directly from the filter call, consider returning a Boolean measure of whether the current item is a match. Save the resulting filtered selection in a variable. After filtering, you can toggle that selection as a whole:

```
var $filtered = $items.filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1;
});

$items.toggle(false);
$filtered.toggle(true);
```

This hides all items and then shows only the filtered items.
You might even consider some fading animation:

```
$items.hide(250);
$filtered.stop(true,false).show(250);
```

Then you can reference the filtered selection's [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/).
If it's zero, show the "not found" message:

```
var hasMatches = $filtered.length;

if (hasMatches) {
  // there were matches.
} else {
  // no matches.
}
```

You can also pass a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector) to a filter. jQuery's  [`:contains()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selects "all elements that contain the specified text", which makes a nice choice.

**Working Example:**

```js
var $items = $('.item');
var $none = $('#none');
var fade = 250;

function filterContent() {

  // get word from value of clicked button.
  var word = this.value;

  // hide items; filter; show filtered; count matches
  var hasMatches = $items
    .hide(fade)
    .filter(':contains(' + word + ')')
    .stop(true, false)
    .show(fade)
    .length;

  // if no matches, show message.
  if (hasMatches) {
    $none.hide(fade);
  } else {
    $none.show(fade);
  }

}

$('button').on('click', filterContent);
```

```css
#none {
  display: none;
  color: darkred;
}

#buttons {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">Here is some text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some other text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some other different text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is something else.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some additional text.</div>

<div id="none">No matches found.</div>

<nav id="buttons">
  <button type="button" value="">all</button>
  <button type="button" value="text">text</button>
  <button type="button" value="other">other</button>
  <button type="button" value="additional">additional</button>
  <button type="button" value="bazooka">bazooka</button>
</nav>
```

---

**Another way:**

If you prefer, you can toggle inside the filter as long as you still return the state Boolean from the function. I suggest making a separate function to pass to the filter. In this case, `toggleItem()` determines the state of an item (match or non-match), toggles the item according to that state, and returns the state.

```js
var $items = $('.item');
var $none = $('#none');

function toggleItem(word) {
  return function(k, el) {
    var $item = $(el);
    var state = $item.text().indexOf(word) > -1;
    $item.toggle(state);
    return state;
  }
}

function filterContent() {

  // get word from value of clicked button.
  var word = this.value;

  // filter while toggling and count result.
  var hasMatches = $items
    .filter(toggleItem(word))
    .length;

  // if no matches, show message.
  $none.toggle(!hasMatches);

}

$('button').on('click', filterContent);
```

```css
#none {
  display: none;
  color: darkred;
}

#buttons {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">Here is some text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some other text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some other different text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is something else.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some additional text.</div>

<div id="none">No matches found.</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" value="">all</button>
  <button type="button" value="text">text</button>
  <button type="button" value="other">other</button>
  <button type="button" value="additional">additional</button>
  <button type="button" value="bazooka">bazooka</button>
</div>
```

In my opinion, this is a bit harder to read and not as clear as the chained "hide,filter,show,length" commands, but that's somewhat a matter of style. You can see that there are many ways to bake this cake!

This one's pretty short and sweet:

```js
var $none = $("#none");
var $items = $(".item");

$("button").click(function() {

  var value = $(this).data('value');

  $items.each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1);
  });

  $none.toggle(!$items.filter(':visible').length);

});
```

```css
#none {
  display: none;
  color: darkred;
}

#buttons {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">Here is some text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some other text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some other different text.</div>
<div class="item">Here is something else.</div>
<div class="item">Here is some additional text.</div>

<div id="none">No matches found.</div>

<nav id="buttons">
  <button type="button" data-value="">all</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="text">text</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="other">other</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="additional">additional</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="bazooka">bazooka</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` returns the value. Check if the length is 1 or more.

```js
$(".filter").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text(); //Get the text of the button
  var result = $("div").hide().filter(function(i, o) { //Hide All and filter
    return $(o).text().includes(value); //Return true if the content of div contains text of the button
  }).show(); //Show all result


  if (result.length) { //Check the length of the result
    //Found match/es
    $(".msg").text('');
  } else {
    //No match
    $(".msg").text(`${value} not found`);
  }
});

$(".show-all").click(function() {
  $("div").show();
});
```

```css
.msg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="msg"></span>

<br /><br />

<div> apple </div>
<div> orange </div>
<div> rock melon</div>
<div> pineapple </div>
<div> pineapple pie</div>

<br /><br />

<button class="filter">example</button>
<button class="filter">pineapple</button>
<button class="filter">rock</button>

<br /><br />

<button class="show-all">Show all</button>
```

Comment: Weird. It seems that the snippet console is inside `<body>`, so the text that is outputted by `console.log()` gets matched by the div filter and causes confusing results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to count match item.

```
$("button").click(function(){
var value = $(this).data('value').toUpperCase();
var count = 0;
$("div").filter(function(index) {

  if($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) count++;

  $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1)

  });
  if(count == 0) alert('Not match');
});
```

```js
$("button").click(function(){
var value = $(this).data('value').toUpperCase();
var count = 0;
$("div").filter(function(index) {

  if($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) count++;
  
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1)
  
  });
  if(count == 0) alert('Not match');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>TEST1</div>
<div>example</div>
<div>test1</div>


<button data-value='test1'>example</button>
```